# How to upper-bound the Binomial coefficient with a Polynomial?

Tags: combinatorics, elementary-number-theory, binomial-coefficients, upper-lower-bounds

I want to upper-bound the following Binomial coefficient with a Polynomial $p(n)\in O(n^c)$:
$$
{n \choose k}=\frac{n!}{k!\cdot\left(n-k\right)!}\leq p(n)
$$
I know that $k\leq n$ but which $p(n)$ I can always use here?

EDIT: The question is coming from the following case:

$$
{n\choose n-17}\leq n^{17}
$$
but for some reason you can't upper-bound ${n \choose 0.5n}$. why?

Comment: It's better to use the classical definition $\dbinom{n}{k} = \dfrac{n\left(n-1\right)\cdots\left(n-k+1\right)}{k!}$.

Comment: The largest binomial coefficient $\binom n k$ appears when (for fixed $n$) $k$ is as close as possible to $n/2$.  Those entries grow faster than any polynomial in $n$.

Comment: It is known that $$
\binom{n}{n/2} \sim \frac{{2^{n + 1/2} }}{{\sqrt {\pi n} }}
$$ so you cannot have an upper bound which is a polynomial of $n$.

Comment: @Gary:  The OP has added a bit of context, so perhaps your Comment should be elaborated into an Answer.

Comment: Your initial question wasn't clear. It seems you're asking to upper bound $n \choose k$ for fixed $k$. Since ${n \choose k} = \frac{n(n-1)\cdots (n-k+1)}{k!} \lt \frac{n^k}{k!}$ it's clear that ${n \choose k} = O(n^k)$. Since it's also a polynomial with leading term $cn^k$, it is $\Omega(n^k)$. But if $k$ is variable, the leading term is $cn^{g(n)}$, and that explains why $n \choose n/2$ is no longer polynomial.